# jQuery UI state-focus is activated when switching tabs of web browser

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using the jQuery UI vertical slider, and when I click on a new tab of a web browser (Firefox, Chrome, and IE) the state-focus is activated for no apparent reason of the slider.

When I click on the slider that state-focus goes away, and when I click on the window there is no state focus (which is what it's suppose to do.), only switching tabs.

I know this is a bug but I can't find the piece of code to remedy it. Help?

I'm using jQuery UI 1.8.21.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a bug, and I cannot reproduce it ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wf6WK/)). Do you have a `focus` or `blur` event handler bound to `window` that could explain this?

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved by separating the ui-state-focus from ui-state-active in jquery ui slider-vertical's default css.

So the bug doesn't effect the presentation of the slider.

Here's similar problems user are having:

[jQuery UI button not "unclicking"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800641/jquery-ui-button-not-unclicking)
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/button-and-dialog-ui-state-focus-on-button-being-kept